# (Wordpress) How to disable scrolling down when pressing spacebar?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

how am I supposed to disable scrolling down when pressing spacebar in Wordpress? 
I found a code like this one

`window.onkeydown = function(e) { 
    return !(e.keyCode == 32);
};`

(with enters of course but I don't know how to create them)

But I have NO CLUE where and how to paste/install it. I would be thankful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your theme's functions.php. It can be found at `/wp-content/themes/{theme-name}/functions.php`.

```
function disable_spacebar_in_wp() { ?>
   <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         window.onkeydown = function(e) { return !(e.keyCode == 32); };
      });          
   </script>
<?php } add_action('wp_head', 'disable_spacebar_in_wp', PHP_INT_MAX);
```